# Getting the node ID of a page making a $.post request

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

So in my module I'm making a $.post to a drupal menu callback. Is there some way to find out which node the user is doing the $.post from on serverside? Thanks.

Sample code that doesn't work:

```
function module_menu() {
  $items = array();

    $items['checkNID'] = array(
        'title' => 'Check Users',
        'page callback' => 'NIDCheck',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
  return $items;

}


function NIDCheck (){
    $result = array();
    $result['nid'] = arg(1);

    return drupal_json($result);           
}

$.post('/checkNID/', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // this should return the nid
}, "json");
```

Comment: Your question literally makes no sense. "Which node the user is doing the $.post" -- you are missing a verb or something. If it's "Which node is displayed when the user is doing the $.post" -- why dont you just add the node id to Drupal.settings and copy it to the post array in JS?

Comment: @chx sorry for the confusion, I edited the question a bit. Can you explain how to add the node id to the drupal.settings? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are executing the post from the node page itself, you can use

```
$nid = arg(1);
```

arg() will retrieve the value of the drupal path passed in.  IE:

http://example.com/hi/mark/it/is/erik

```
arg(0) = hi
arg(1) = mark
arg(2) = it
...
```

because every node page's url is http://example.com/node/$nid, arg(1) will always return the correct nid, even if the node has an alias.

**EDIT**:

Use preprocess_node() and add a call to drupal_add_js():

```
drupal_add_js(array('my_module' => array('nid' => arg(1)), 'setting');
```

Then in your JS, you can access this value like so:

```
Drupal.settings.my_module.nid
```

Erik

Comment: thanks Erick, but I'm still not sure what to do. I showed some sample code of what I tried that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the nid of the node the user is doing the $.post from in your callback without passing it in your background POST request. When you are in your callback, the request path, as used by arg() is a 'checkNID'. You can't extract the nid from there.

You can use

```
$.post('/checkNID/', {nid: a_var_containing_the_current_page_nid}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, "json");
```

Or, if you actually need to retrieve the node for the nid, you can use Drupal's [wilcard loader argument](http://drupal.org/node/224170):

```
function module_menu() {
  $items = array();

    $items['checkNID/%node'] = array(
        'title' => 'Check Users',
        'page callback' => 'NIDCheck',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
  return $items;
}

function NIDCheck ($node){
    $result = array();
    $result['nid'] = $node->nid;
    return drupal_json($result);           
}
```

And in JS

```
$.post('/checkNID/'+ a_var_containing_the_current_page_nid, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, "json");
```

Most theme outputs the node in a `div` container using `node-$nid` as its id. So, without additional server-side code, you could also retrieve the current page nid in JavaScript with

```
var current_nid = $('div[id^=node-]').attr('id').split('-')[1];
```

You can also store the current page nid in a JavaScript variable from PHP code with [`drupal_add_js`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6). You need to di this on node view (ie. the containing page) and not in `NIDCheck()`. So something like

```
function module_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if($op === 'view') {
    drupal_add_js(array('module' => array('nid' => $node->nid), 'setting');
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately a_var_containing_the_current_page_nid is what I'm trying to find though. Setting it in DOM is useless because in DOM it could easily be faked.